# Load external script in <head> in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, external-script, html-head

I want to load an external script in `<head>`. It is module specific so I want my module to take care of the loading.

In Drupal 6, function [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/6) does not allow to add an external script in `<head>`. It will be available in [Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/7) passing the `"external"` argument to the function. <del>In D6, I can use [`drupal_set_html_head()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_html_head/6) instead, but it inserts the given data in the beginning of the `<head>` which I don't want. **I'd like to append data in it**.</del>

It turned out that `drupal_html_set_head()` appends data.

```
$stored_head .= $data ."\n";
```

So the behavior I experimented--data was inserted in the beginning of head data--should come from that I call `drupal_html_set_head()` in my module's `hook_init()` function.

How can I append data to the very and of `<head>`?

Comment: Why do you insist on *appending* it and not prepending? AFAIK there is no way that order should matter for a browser, since the resources are called in *parrallel* and *asynchonous*, so to me, it appears your request to append is flawed itself.

Comment: @berkes: order does matter. See http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#PutStylesBeforeScripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default *page.tpl.php* (you can find it in */modules/system/page.tpl.php* is this:

```
<head>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
  <script type="text/javascript"><?php /* Needed to avoid Flash of Unstyled Content in IE */ ?> </script>
</head>
```

When you make `drupal_set_html_head()` it is appending stuff to variable `$head`, but still there are more variables appended as you see.

One possible solutions is to append the stuff that you want to `$scripts`, instead of `$head`.

How?

with a preprocess function from your module:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['scripts'] .= $your_stuff;
}
```

I didn't try this solution, but if doesn't work maybe is because the order of execution. Try to set your module's weight higher, so it will run *after* the `system_preprocess_page`.

Other reason why may not work is because the theme is printing the variables in different order in *page.tpl.php*. But you can't control this from the code of a module.

Comment: This is the option I chose. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple solutions to work around the problem.

- use hook_footer() to add the js to the footer
- make a small jquery script, which creates the `<script>` element and adds it to `<head>`
- do it with a template preprocess function
- make your own page.tpl.php

Comment: NB: I want to insert script in `<head>`.

Comment: I implemented the `template_preprocess_page()` hook and it works nice.

Answer (score 2):

Did you see this [comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_html_head/6#comment-2083)?

> Beware when using this to set an external js file call in D6, eg:
>
> drupal_set_html_head('');
>
> If you don't include a full script closing tag (ie ), it will
>   break in Firefox (and possibly other browsers, webkit-based ones seem
>   fine). The tag will fail to close, and will wipe out any other headers
>   up to the next available  tag. This usually results in all
>   your css files failing to load, plus the next fully-tagged js file. So
>   use this form instead:
>
> drupal_set_html_head('');
>
> This applies up to and including Drupal 6.16. You can overcome it in
>   D7 with the new external option in drupal_add_js.

Comment: it tells me how to use it correctly. *I use it correctly.* It's normal behavior to prepend data in `<head>`. I want to **append it**.

Comment: @Török Gábor you are in bad luck then. sorry. Drupal uses the .= operator, prepending it. appending is simply not possible in a _correct_ way.

Comment: Oh, sorry, did not see that part.

Comment: @berkes: i was wrong. It uses the `.=` operator so it *appends*. I call `drupal_set_html_head()` inside `hook_init()`, may be that's the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal uses the `.=` operator to create the `$head` variable. The `$js` and `$css` is kept in an array, and allows you to be re-orderd. 
`$head` is a string, and cannot be re-orderd, othern then by ugly, error-prone hacks. Such as regular-expression explosions, re-ordering and imploding.

```
$heads = preg_explode("\n", $head);
ksort($heads);
$head = implode("\n", $heads);
```

in your theme's variable pre-processor.